# pip install -r requirements.txt with git+https that references another git+https fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

If a `requirements.txt` includes a private repo package via `git+https` and that package contains a `git+https` to another private repo package, the second `git+https` is not recognized.

This is the error when I run `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` in the `Client` project:

`Expected end or semicolon (after name and no valid version specifier)`

Full error:

```
Resolved https://x-token-auth:****@bitbucket.org/name/library1.git
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [66 lines of output]
      /private/var/folders/r3/g2zzxbp952qcpf7z4tlzrsvc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-yejy0smn/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/config/pyprojecttoml.py:66: _BetaConfiguration: Support for `[tool.setuptools]` in `pyproject.toml` is still *beta*.
        config = read_configuration(filepath, True, ignore_option_errors, dist)
      /private/var/folders/r3/g2zzxbp952qcpf7z4tlzrsvc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-yejy0smn/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/config/expand.py:132: SetuptoolsWarning: File '/private/var/folders/r3/g2zzxbp952qcpf7z4tlzrsvc0000gn/T/pip-req-build-2kfhkxk4/README.md' cannot be found
        return '\n'.join(
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/private/var/folders/r3/g2zzxbp952qcpf7z4tlzrsvc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-yejy0smn/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 35, in __init__
          parsed = parse_requirement(requirement_string)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/r3/g2zzxbp952qcpf7z4tlzrsvc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-yejy0smn/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/packaging/_parser.py", line 64, in parse_requirement
          return _parse_requirement(Tokenizer(source, rules=DEFAULT_RULES))
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/r3/g2zzxbp952qcpf7z4tlzrsvc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-yejy0smn/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/packaging/_parser.py", line 82, in _parse_requirement
          url, specifier, marker = _parse_requirement_details(tokenizer)
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/r3/g2zzxbp952qcpf7z4tlzrsvc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-yejy0smn/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/packaging/_parser.py", line 126, in _parse_requirement_details
          marker = _parse_requirement_marker(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/r3/g2zzxbp952qcpf7z4tlzrsvc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-yejy0smn/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/packaging/_parser.py", line 147, in _parse_requirement_marker
          tokenizer.raise_syntax_error(
        File "/private/var/folders/r3/g2zzxbp952qcpf7z4tlzrsvc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-yejy0smn/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/packaging/_tokenizer.py", line 163, in raise_syntax_error
          raise ParserSyntaxError(
      setuptools.extern.packaging._tokenizer.ParserSyntaxError: Expected end or semicolon (after name and no valid version specifier)
          git+https://x-token-auth:****@bitbucket.org/name/library2.git
             ^
      
      The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/username/src/testnestedreq/client/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Users/username/src/testnestedreq/client/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Users/username/src/testnestedreq/client/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/r3/g2zzxbp952qcpf7z4tlzrsvc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-yejy0smn/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/r3/g2zzxbp952qcpf7z4tlzrsvc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-yejy0smn/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/r3/g2zzxbp952qcpf7z4tlzrsvc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-yejy0smn/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/r3/g2zzxbp952qcpf7z4tlzrsvc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-yejy0smn/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 107, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/r3/g2zzxbp952qcpf7z4tlzrsvc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-yejy0smn/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 159, in setup
          dist.parse_config_files()
        File "/private/var/folders/r3/g2zzxbp952qcpf7z4tlzrsvc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-yejy0smn/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 908, in parse_config_files
          pyprojecttoml.apply_configuration(self, filename, ignore_option_errors)
        File "/private/var/folders/r3/g2zzxbp952qcpf7z4tlzrsvc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-yejy0smn/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/config/pyprojecttoml.py", line 67, in apply_configuration
          return _apply(dist, config, filepath)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/r3/g2zzxbp952qcpf7z4tlzrsvc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-yejy0smn/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/config/_apply_pyprojecttoml.py", line 49, in apply
          dist._finalize_requires()
        File "/private/var/folders/r3/g2zzxbp952qcpf7z4tlzrsvc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-yejy0smn/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 607, in _finalize_requires
          self._move_install_requirements_markers()
        File "/private/var/folders/r3/g2zzxbp952qcpf7z4tlzrsvc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-yejy0smn/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 647, in _move_install_requirements_markers
          inst_reqs = list(_reqs.parse(spec_inst_reqs))
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/r3/g2zzxbp952qcpf7z4tlzrsvc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-yejy0smn/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 37, in __init__
          raise InvalidRequirement(str(e)) from e
      setuptools.extern.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Expected end or semicolon (after name and no valid version specifier)
          git+https://x-token-auth:****@bitbucket.org/name/library2.git
             ^
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

To demonstrate the problem, I have 3 projects:

1. `Client`: Includes dependency to `Library1`
2. `Library1`: Includes dependency to `Library2`
3. `Library2`: Does stuff

`Client` `requirements.txt`:

```
python-dotenv==1.0.0
git+https://x-token-auth:****@bitbucket.org/name/library1.git@main
```

`Library1` `requirements.txt`:

```
python-dotenv==1.0.0
git+https://x-token-auth:****@bitbucket.org/name/library2.git@main
```

`Library2 requirements.txt`:

```
python-dotenv==1.0.0
```

Environment:

1. Mac Ventura 13.2, M1 chip
2. python 3.11.1
3. pip 23.1.2
4. setuptools 65.5.0
5. Using virtual environment via `python3 -m venv venv` and `source venv/bin/activate`

Tried these things:

1. If I run `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` from the `Library1` project, then it works fine.
2. If I remove `Library2` dependency from `Library1` then it passes the error (but I can't use `Library2`)
3. If I directly add `Library2` to `Client`'s `requirements.txt` then everything is fine.  But this is not ideal because it requires `Client` to explicitly know `Library1`'s dependency

How can I get this scenario to work?